# Update column from another table based on matching column value using fuzzy logic

Tags: sql-server

How to update a column from another table on the basis of percentage of matching of two another column of two tables

e.g Suppose i have table Company1 having column Address1 and CompanyName1 and another table Company2 having column Address2 and CompanyName2 .I want to update CompanyName1 of Company1 table from Company2 on the basis of Address1 and Address2
matching percent value.
Please suggest me a efficient running query

Comment: Please, specify what percentage you are talking about and how to count it? Also it would be nice to provide sample data and required output.

Comment: suppose i have Address2 of Company2 table is "6716 Madison Ave # A1" and CompanyName2 is "Hamby Chiropractic" and in Company1 table i have Address1 as "6716 Madison"  so I want to update CompanyName1 of Company1 table from Company2 on the basis of Address1 and Address2 matching percent value say 70% matching

Comment: Do you know how to count 70% of matching?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment:

```
;WITH Company2 as (
SELECT  'Hamby Chiropractic' as CompanyName2,
        '6716 Madison Ave # A1' as Address2
), Company1 as (
SELECT  NULL as CompanyName1,
        '6716 Madison' as Address1
)

SELECT *, LEN(c1.Address1)*100.00/LEN(c2.Address2)
FROM Company1 c1
LEFT JOIN Company2 c2
    ON c2.Address2 LIKE '%' + c1.Address1 +'%'
    OR c1.Address1 LIKE '%' + c2.Address2 +'%'
```

I will get

```
CompanyName1    Address1        CompanyName2        Address2                (No column name)
NULL            6716 Madison    Hamby Chiropractic  6716 Madison Ave # A1   57.1428571428571
```

I have counted the percent based on the length of strings. Is that sufficient enough for you?